# Arduino (line follower + ultrasonic sensor + servomotor)

Tags: ultrasonics

I am making a line follower car that follows the line when push button is pressed. And by using ultrasonic sensor I want the car to stop when object ahead distance is closer than 100 and then make servo motor turn to 180 degrees.

Used:

- Arduino UNO
- 2 DC motor
- cytron maker line sensor
- 1 servo motor
- 1 ultrasonic sensor
- 1 push button.

Got stuck coding, I would like some help please.

```cpp
int E1 = 4;
int M1 = 5; // Right
int M2 = 6; // Left
int E2 = 7;
int trigPin = 4;
int echoPin = 5;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  pinMode(E1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(E2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M2, OUTPUT);
  
  digitalWrite(E1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(E2, HIGH);
  
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}


void loop() {
  float duration, distance;
  
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = ((float)(340 * duration) / 1000) / 2;
  
  Serial.print("\nDIstance:");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println("mm\n");
  delay(200);
  
  int D1 = digitalRead(8);
  int D2 = digitalRead(9);
  int D3 = digitalRead(10);
  int D4 = digitalRead(11);
  int D5 = digitalRead(12);
  
  if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 0 && D3 == 1 && D4 == 0 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 100);
    analogWrite(M2, 100);
  }
  else if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 1 && D3 == 1 && D4 == 0 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 80);
    analogWrite(M2, 100);
  }
  else if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 1 && D3 == 0 && D4 == 0 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 60);
    analogWrite(M2, 100);
  }
  else if (D1 == 1 && D2 == 1 && D3 == 0 && D4 == 0 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 30);
    analogWrite(M2, 100);
  }
  else if (D1 == 1 && D2 == 0 && D3 == 0 && D4 == 0 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 0);
    analogWrite(M2, 100);
  }
  else if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 0 && D3 == 1 && D4 == 1 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 100);
    analogWrite(M2, 80);
  }
  else if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 0 && D3 == 0 && D4 == 1 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 100);
    analogWrite(M2, 60);
  }
  else if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 0 && D3 == 0 && D4 == 1 && D5 == 1) {
    analogWrite(M1, 100);
    analogWrite(M2, 30);
  }
  else if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 0 && D3 == 0 && D4 == 0 && D5 == 1) {
    analogWrite(M1, 100);
    analogWrite(M2, 0);
  }
  else if (D1 == 0 && D2 == 0 && D3 == 0 && D4 == 0 && D5 == 0) {
    analogWrite(M1, 0);
    analogWrite(M2, 0);
  }
  else if (D1 == 1 && D2 == 1 && D3 == 1 && D4 == 1 && D5 == 1) {
    analogWrite(M1, 00);
    analogWrite(M2, 00);
  }
  else {
  }
}
```

Comment: Stuck how? What's the specific issue?

Comment: (Unrelated, but consider naming things to be a bit more descriptive, e.g., if you have to comment `M1` with `right` just name it `rightMotor` or something :) Might also be convenient to move some of the code out of `loop` into separate functions to help figure out what's going on.)

Comment: this coding doesn't detect the distance it prints 0 everytime I'm guessing if it is in the wrong order

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int M1 = 5; // Right
...
int echoPin = 5;
```

You appear to be trying to use one of your motors on the same pin as your return signal from the ultrasonic range finder.  When `analogWrite(M1, whatever)`, the internals of `analogWrite` will [set the pin to output](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/1.8.3/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c#L111), overriding your own `pinMode(echoPin, INPUT)` in `setup()`.

Later when you `pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH)`, you're just seeing whatever `analogWrite` is doing with it.  If you're not touching any buttons, your code is executing `analogWrite(M1, 0);`, so no "distance".

For more fun:  If all of this is correct, if you hold down the buttons to execute `analogWrite(M1, 100)`, `pulseIn` should report a value of about (1.0/980) * 100/256 or 399.  The 980 being the frequency pin 5 uses on the UNO for [analogWrite](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/).  This should cause your code to print something around 66.